# Rendering multiple DOM elements from different HTML pages in the same app.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am a complete newbie with ReactJs or UI coding, in general. I have a single entry point in my ReactJs app - app.js

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
import Main from "./components/Main";
import Bucket from "./components/Bucket";
import Relay from "react-relay";

ReactDOM.render(<Main />,document.getElementById('react'));
ReactDOM.render(<Bucket />,document.getElementById('react-bucket'));

console.log(Relay.QL`query Test {ServerGroups {_id}}`);
```

I am trying to render the buckets.html page here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RGR</title>
<script src="react-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="react-dom-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="react-bucket"></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

When I go to the index.html page, everything renders fine. But when I go to the buckets.html page, I get a

**Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element** error

When i try to render just one element in app.js (comment out either the Main component render or the Bucket component render) , again, both components render fine. So there is no problem with the components themselves.

There is obviously a problem getting app.js read from both buckets.html and index.html. How can I access buckets.html and index.html in such a situation? Is it even possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly problematic to try and split your project into multiple HTML files like that. It sort of defeats one of the superpowers of React - making a SPA or "Single Page App". The "React-ful" way to do this would actually be to use React-Router.

React-Router lets you specify "routes" in your project, so you could have, say, `example.com/` and `example.com/bucket` render different components inside of your project, without having to actually change the page. Check out [this demo](http://react-router-mega-demo.herokuapp.com/) to get a sense of what I mean.

I highly suggest you do your own research and check out the [React-Router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), but it would probably look something like this:

```
let App = (
   <Router>
       <Route path="/" component={Main} />
       <Route path="/bucket" component={Bucket} />
   </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('react'));
```

Now when you go to `example.com/`, React will render the `<Main />` component, and if you go to `example.com/bucket` it will render `<Bucket />`. This is a highly simplified example - there are other things to consider like `<Link />`s, default routes, 404, server side handling, etc. But this is pretty much exactly what you need, very modern, and tailor made for React.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look through and hopefully be able to change the app to have this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is evident as the error suggests , you are trying to render the Main component in an Element with id `React` but it doesn't exist in your HTML file

Add it in HTML file like

```
<body>
<div id="react"></div>
<div id="react-bucket"></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is not with the html, but whether it is possible for single app.js render from multiple htmls. What is the best way to render different pages, if not? One option is to use react-router.

Comment: You can have as many ReactDOM.render as you need, but in this kind of situation I prefer using ReactRouter

Answer (score 0):

`ReactDOM.render(<Main />,document.getElementById('react'));`

There is no Dom element by the Id of 'react'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>RGR</title>
<script src="react-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="react-dom-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="react"></div>
  <div id="react-bucket"></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

This should work just fine if the components are correct on their own

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is not with the html, but whether it is possible for single app.js render from multiple htmls. What is the best way to render different pages, if not? One option is to use react-router.